# while statement still adding blank line even when false?

Tags: java, android

Here's my code. I have a file with and odd number of lines. I still get a blank button at the end. If I change it to an even number of lines, it works fine. 
I want it to read the number of lines and add a button for each line no matter if there are an even or odd amount of lines. 
What am I doing wrong.
Thanks,

```
        // This builds the number of rows based on the number of lines in the file.
        while (line != null){

            TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);
            tblRow.setPadding(5, 30, 5, 5);
            table.addView(tblRow);

            // iterates through the number of lines.
            // filling each cell with a button with the name of each part in the file.
            for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COL; col++) {
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setTextSize(14);
                btn.setText(line);
                btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                tblRow.addView(btn);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        };
```

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: I tried a catch but nothing shows up in the IOException. If I move the line reader out of the for, it just loops forever.

Comment: Here's what I get in debug mode - Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8624): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

Comment: What is the value of `NUM_COL` and how do you set it?

Comment: Got the debugger to work, but still nothing shows up as wrong.

Comment: private final int NUM_COL = 2;

Comment: Nobody wants to take a crack at solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this

```
 while (line != null){

        TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);
        tblRow.setPadding(5, 30, 5, 5);
        table.addView(tblRow);

        for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COL; col++) {
            if (line != null) {
                //Normal flow
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setTextSize(14);
                btn.setText(line);
                btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                tblRow.addView(btn);
                line = reader.readLine();
             }else{
                //Guaranteed to happen on odd number of lines since NUM_COL=2
                //Might want to add a dummy view here if the missing button affects the table display

                //NOP

             }

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. Two things happen, first nothing shows up at all now. Second, if I add table.addview before the for statement and leave it in the else I get one row with two col. If I remove it from the else, I get one row with all the buttons on that row.  But I think we're getting closer.

Comment: The rest you should have kept

Comment: Okay, ran it again just like you said. I get an error this time.  --   The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. --  I'm lost. I assume this is because the table.addview is called first under the while, then again in the else when the line is blank.

Comment: You are right. THe else should not do that. Use the else clause only if you need to ad a dummy view